# Deserialize JSON array into a dictionary with keys provided separately from the JSON

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "price": ["123.50", "124.6", "126.30"],
    "order": ["23", "30", "20"]
}
```

I want to fill my object `Product`:

```
public class Product {
  public Dictionary<string, Object> priceInfo;
  public Dictionary<string, Object> orderInfo;
}
```

I have with each JSON object a description for each value (here with array) maybe in `Product` class, for example:

```
String[] defPriceInfo = {"price", "avgprice", "maxprice"};
```

Finally I would access these values of the `Product` object with `priceInfo.TryGetValue("avgprice", ...)`, which would return to me the value

> 124.6

I searched in Stack Overflow but I didn't find a similar problem.
Actually I tried to override `JsonConverter.ReadJson` but it didn't work; the problem is the personalized "keys" that I want.

**Edit1** : I have this for `ReadJson()` method but that's wrong.

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            object res = new Object();
            var tokenType = reader.TokenType;
            if (tokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                 object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                 res = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            else if (tokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                res = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *maybe in Item class*?  There's no `Item` class in your question.  Did you mean the `Product` class?  If so, can you give a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a class you want to serialize & deserialize in this manner, and what you tried so far in `ReadJson()`?

Comment: Yes sorry for the mistake i changed Item by Product. I mean that's is "maybe" not the best solution. But actually i see just that solution. I also thinking load the informations with file. I will post what i tried. The problem with the solution that i have tried is that i don't know how i can pass the "keys" descriptor at my class for each value that i read.

Comment: @dbc I added my example but this is completly wrong. I don't understand how this works

Comment: Would the same `defPriceInfo ` keys be used for the both the JSON arrays, or would you have a different set of keys for the `order` array?

Comment: @BrianRogers No just for PriceInfo, I supposed we have 'defOrderInfo' for the other json array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach using a custom `JsonConverter` as a generic solution.  The idea is that you set up a public, static, readonly, string array containing the keys for each dictionary that you want to handle specially, then mark each dictionary field with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute which specifies where to find the static field containing the keys array.  The converter then populates the dictionary from the JSON array using the keys specified.  (Note that if the JSON array property name differs from the dictionary member name in your class, you'll also need a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to tie them together.)

Here is how you would set it up your example `Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public static readonly string[] defPriceInfo = { "price", "avgprice", "maxprice" };
    public static readonly string[] defOrderInfo = { "first", "second", "third" };

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToDictionaryConverter), typeof(Product), "defPriceInfo")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> priceInfo;

    [JsonProperty("order")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToDictionaryConverter), typeof(Product), "defOrderInfo")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> orderInfo;
}
```

And here is the code for the custom `ArrayToDictionaryConverter`:

```
class ArrayToDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private string[] keysArray;

    public ArrayToDictionaryConverter(Type containingObjectType, string keysArrayFieldName)
    {
        FieldInfo field = containingObjectType.GetField(keysArrayFieldName);
        if (field == null)
            throw new Exception("Could not find " + keysArrayFieldName + " field on type " + containingObjectType.Name + ".");
        if (!field.Attributes.HasFlag(FieldAttributes.Static) || field.FieldType != typeof(String[]))
            throw new Exception("The " + keysArrayFieldName + " field on " + containingObjectType.Name + " must be declared as static string[].");
        keysArray = (string[])field.GetValue(null);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            string key = i < keysArray.Length ? keysArray[i] : "key" + i;
            dict.Add(key, (string)array[i]);
        }

        return dict;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is a quick demo showing how it works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
            {
                ""price"": [""123.50"", ""124.6"", ""126.30""],
                ""order"": [""23"", ""30"", ""20""]
            }";

        try
        {
            Product prod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
            foreach (var kvp in prod.priceInfo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
            }
            foreach (var kvp in prod.orderInfo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null) Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
price: 123.50
avgprice: 124.6
maxprice: 126.30
first: 23
second: 30
third: 20
```

Comment: Thanks but I have an error because"the JsonConverterAttribute constructor doesn't have 3 parameters"

Comment: Support for additional parameters on the [`JsonConverterAttribute` constructor](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor_1.htm) was added in [Json.Net version 6.0.6](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/6.0.6) (Oct 20, 2014).  If you are using an older version you'll need to upgrade.  [Current version](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases) as of now is 8.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by first deserializing the JSON to a POCO, using for example a class like this:

```
public class TempProduct 
{
  public Price price {get; set;}
  public Order order {get; set;}

  public class Price
  {
    public string price {get; set;}
    public string avgprice {get; set;}
    public string maxprice {get; set;}
  }

  public class Order
  {
    public string orderType1 {get; set;}
    public string orderType2 {get; set;}
    public string orderType3 {get; set;}
  }
}
```

You could then populate your Product class from this e.g.

```
var prod = new Product();

prod.priceInfo = new Dictionary<string,Object>();
prod.priceInfo.Add("price", tempProd.price.price);
prod.priceInfo.Add("avgprice", tempProd.price.avgprice);
prod.priceInfo.Add("maxprice", tempProd.price.maxprice);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this solution will be suitable to my problem. I don't want multiply the classes because i want something be generic.